# What are the allowed Modes in Dynamics AX TextIO Class?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

The MSDN Page at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/textio.new.aspx
just states "Specify one the following: " but the following list is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the class did not change the possible mode values from 2009 to 2012 (those mode values are somewhat general across languages/frameworks anyway) so you may want to have a look at the [page for AX 2009](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa881745(v=ax.50).aspx)

> The mode in which the file should be opened. Specify one the
>   following:
>   R - Read
>   W - Write
>   A - Append (implies "W")
>   T - Translate (text)
>   B - Binary

Comment: thanks! I also found the "File" Macro where those io modes are defined, there is no explanation though.